# Why is rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap different between repository and deb distributions in electric?

Tags: rosjava, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In trying to build a rosjava package that a co-worker built using a source install of rosjava on a machine that had rosjava installed via debian/ubuntu packages I noticed there are very important differences.

Comparing:

- http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/browse/?name=electric-tag

to the version I have installed from deb, it appears that the deb versions simply are missing large chunks of important python code from rosjava_bootstrap/src. Specifically make.py

Anyone know why this difference exists?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11519/why-is-rosjava_core/rosjava_bootstrap-different-between-repository-and-deb-distributions-in-electric?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-10-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosjava is still in an alpha state with the packaging/toolchain integrating under flux.  The debian package is not directly tracking these changes as these packaging changes affect the ability to produce debian binaries.

NOTE: to verify versions:

```
$ rosversion rosjava_core
```

or,

```
$ tail -1 CMakeLists.txt 
rosbuild_make_distribution(0.2.0)
```

or (for the debian release version number, if you want to check before you install)

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava_core/Releases
http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosjava_core/Releases

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-10-13**:
Oh great! I was unaware of rosversion, or the fact that the version number was embedded in the CMakeLists.txt. Thanks!

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-10-13**:
$ rosversion rosjava_core
0.2.0

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-10-13**:
It doesn't seem that the version information is anywhere in the stack/package, nor on it's official page. Is knowing this more or less ad-hoc? (I ask as someone trying to manage version control across projects) Might this be something I should write up a REP about?

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-10-13**:
In general, if something is < 1.0, you shouldn't expect the debs to stay up-to-date.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-10-13**:
Is there any formal way to know when a package is alpha/likely to be out of sync with debs? I see in stack.xml and manifest.xml 'review status="unreviewed" ' but am unsure if that would be a reliable indicator.